# scraping only a particular tag without details from nested tag in that particular tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have a page where the structure is something like

```
<body>
    <article>  <!--article no 1-->
        <h3>
        <h2>
            <h1>
                <a>  <!--first 'a' tag-->

        <article> <!--article no 2-->
            <h1>
            <h2>
                <a>  <!--second 'a' tag-->
        </article>       
    </article>
</body>
```

Now what I want is I want to extract all 'a' tags inside an article but such that no 'a' tag comes from any nested

that is

```
articles = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
for i in article:
    print(i.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
```

for first article 
now i.find_elements will return all 'a' tags inside this article tag which will also include 'a' tags inside 'article tag' that is itself nested in current article tag but i dont want that

I want if i call find_elements on article no 1 'a' tags in article no 2 or in any nested article should not come

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to extract anything from the nested (parent) `<article> <!--article no 2-->` tag?

Comment: yes I dont want details from any nested article

Comment: Can you update the _HTML_ with the parent tag of the `<article>  <!--article no 1-->` tag?

Comment: i didnt get you ?

Comment: The parent tag/node of our desired tag i.e. `<article> <!--article no 1-->` would have been helpful

Comment: we can take it as body

Comment: I feel your _usecase_ is pretty much a boundary condition, so the exact html would have been helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want links from not nested articles, try:

```
articles = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('article'):
for article in articles:
    print(article.find_elements_by_xpath('./*[not(descendant-or-self::article)]/descendant-or-self::a'))
```

Comment: what if I have an article object article=articles[0]?will it work like article.find_elements_by_xpath('a[count(ancestor::article) = 1]') and will it return 'a' tags only within this article tag and not from any other article tags nested in this tag

Comment: Yep. In this way `article.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[count(ancestor::article) = 1]')`

Comment: yep that worked for parent article but what if I have an instance of nested article i.e article=articles[1] where articles[1] article is nested inside articles[0] and i dont want details from any other article tag nested inside articles[1]

Comment: It should work for nested articles also. But IMHO you should initially skip that nested articles as `articles = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//article[not(ancestor::article)]')`

Comment: I didnt get you. actually I want details of all article tags whether it is nested or not.But the point is for one particular article I dont want any details from anyother nested article inside that particular article

Comment: `.//a[count(ancestor::article) = 1]` will match links from *not nested articles only*, no matter how you execute that line. E.g. `articles[0].find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[count(ancestor::article) = 1]')` will return link, `articles[1].find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[count(ancestor::article) = 1]')` will not return links

Comment: why the second part will not return links?I want that as well

Answer (score 0):

Parse the `article` element with `BeautifulSoup` and get all the anchor tags in ease.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
articles = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("article")
links = []
for i in articles:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i.get_attribute('outerHTML'), 'html5lib')
    a_tags = soup.findAll('a')
    links.extend(a_tags)
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: my question does not ask for a tags inside nested articles

Comment: Oops! My bad! Thanks for notifyiing my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

using BeautifulSoup,

try to find all `<a>` under `<articla>` like ('article a')

then use find_parents() method of beautifulsoup.

If length of ('article a').find_parents('article') is bigger than 2, that might be nested like this.

```
<article>
  ..
 <article>
    ..
    <a>
```

so if you remove them you will get `<a>` that has only one `<article>` parent

```
all_a = soup.findAll('article a')

direct_a = [i for i in all_a if len(i)>2]
```